# Species Identification and Care

Tags: species-identification, botany

We've had this plant for a while as one of two. And both have grown incredibly over the last year. We actually know very little about these beyond watering when they look a little sad and would like to look after them better.

We can see that the plant has a 'trunk' of sorts now. Should this be under the soil? Are the plants large enough to repot? Should I change the soil?

The pot is 28cm wide at the widest and the plant is 32 cm high from the soil.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the many [Yucca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yucca) species, probably *[Yucca gigantea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yucca_gigantea)* as this appears to be the spineless form with floppy leaves.

The trunk should protrude from the soil, indeed this species can get quite large with several trunks/branches, each with a cluster of leaves on the tip.

They are hardy indoor and outdoor plants which grow best in full sunshine and dry warm conditions. They are not particularly frost tolerant, but will survive light frosts with maybe some damage to the leaves if in a sheltered spot.

They do best in free-draining soil which retain some water and nutrients (so don't go to cactus extremes), something like 1/3 peat with 2/3 sand should do fine. They are drought tolerant and have generally low water requirements. You should be able to re-pot this plant without any problems every second year. Just water the day before, remove from the pot and replace some of the soil. Alternatively they will do well with a feeding roughly monthly of a balanced liquid feed.